# PHP mod_rewrite on all url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I hope you can help, I've tried for hours to understand mod rewrite but I just seem to be getting no where.

What I'm trying to achieve is a mod_rewrite that takes the whole url as a var unless it begins with something like '/images/.....' etc

the idea being that all my pages are in a table and then found and processed from then on.

Currently I have

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1
```

This works to a point, 
any URL I can get using $_GET which is great, but I don't want to use request_filename conditions,

id like in the rewrite rule to exclude if url == '/images/' or == /css/ etc

Hopefully this makes sense, and i'm sure this is easy.
Also if you have any thought about how to improve the way im trying to achieve this that'd be of use then please let me know.

Cheers!

---

currently got

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/images/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/css/ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1
```

thanks to Alexander but $_GET['url'] == 'index.php'

Comment: I am stuck again and cannot find the answer. My htaccess looks like RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/jobs/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/javascript/
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1    this is fine until I actually want to use a get var in a url so like www.domain.com/login.htm?redirect=123 . the login.htm returns as $_GET['url'] but do not know how to keep any other get vars after that to work as usual, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a rule for those directories first and use the `[L]` flag.

```
RewriteRule ^images/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^css/ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1
```

An untested alternative could be also:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: I've tested this and bother of them rewriteConds work however now the url always returns 'index.php'

Comment: I have sorted it now, i'm not 100% sure this is how I want it work, but I removed the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f and RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d which for some reason resulted in just index.php, but now that i have added them again it works